# Ionic 6 hide part of datetime header

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic6

I am using Ionic 6 with Angular. I have a datetime component and I have set the `title` slot, such as:

```
<ion-datetime [showDefaultTitle]="false" presentation="date">
  <span slot="title">Title</span>
</ion-datetime>
```

The issue is that this displays my title as subtitle and another title containing the currently selected date as the header. On their example in their own [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime#customizing-the-title) this is not even there.

My question is how can I remove this additional header?

It is added with the class `datetime-selected-date`. I tried not displaying this class by setting the property `display: none` but it does not do the trick even when doing this with `::ng-deep`.

[image: Additional title]

Comment: If you put it on ios mode it disappears.

Comment: Thanks! But how to make it also disappear in Android?

Comment: It seems if you just put your title outside of the datetime element you can style yours as you prefer

Answer (score 1):

I have used this structure to display a title above the date picker, without displaying the date in the title:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>...</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime>...</ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: This one was just too obvious for me, so I needed this answer :D Thanks!